# Programmatically start application on login

Tags: windows

What's the best way to programmatically start an application on login for Windows? I know you can do it by adding an item to the startup folder in the start menu, but I want to have an option in my application to turn it off and on.

Comment: BTW, I'd retag 'auto' and 'start' into 'auto-start', but that's just me =8-)

Comment: For the record, I'm sure you can programmatically create shortcuts too, but I'd go with the registry version. I'm pretty sure the startup menu is more or less depricated at this point.

Comment: Retagged auto + start = autostart

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how you could do it in C#:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",
          "MyStartUp",
          @"C:\StartUpApp.exe");
```

You basically need to add a registry entry. The above one works on start-up. There are a few more. I recommend that you download a tool like [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to see all possible locations.

Comment: Cool, i should be able to do that in c++ using windows functions. Thanks

Comment: Beware: the above code adds the autostart entry for all users. Also, you need to have admin rights to write to HKLM. I'd recommend changing  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing. Piskvor++, once again wishing we could upvote comments.

Comment: Oh, you can also use the RunOnce key instead of the Run key to run things once (as the name would suggest) instead of all the time, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 3):

How about installing your program as a Windows service? Services can be switched between 'disabled', 'manual' and 'automatic', and you can access services from within your code (even from a Java application) and manipulate its state.

Just a thought.

Yuval =8-)

Comment: Services don't start at login, they start when you boot the machine before any users are logged in.