# Launch program after each login

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, authentication

I have tried to find this everywhere on the internet with no luck. I want to make my program launch after every login (LoginUI.exe). Is it possible to detect when the user has locked his/her computer (Winkey + L) and then launch my program? If this is not possible, then is there a way to detect once a user has just logged in?

Comment: What are you wanting to do with this program..? are you wanting to monitor Idle time? Key Strokes? ect...?

Comment: i just wan't it to start up when it detects someone has logged on the computer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a program that monitors the user session state via `SystemEvents` in `Microsoft.Win32`:

```
// Put this somewhere in your console app/windows form initialization code.
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += OnSessionSwitch;

// Put this method in your console app/windows form somewhere.
static void OnSessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Reason)
  {
    case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon:
      // User has logged on to the computer.
      break;

    case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogoff:
      // User has logged off from the computer.
      break;

    case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
      // The computer has been unlocked.
      break;

    case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
      // The computer has been locked.
      break;
  }
}
```

In your case, you could do `Process.Start(...)` when you detect either `SessionLogon` or `SessionUnlock`.

Comment: this is good but it can't figure out what "SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;" that is it keeps poping up with "sessionswitch is used like a event when its a type"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SO already has some information on this type of thing.  A registry modification in c# looks like it will do the trick.

[Programmatically start application on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385793/programmatically-start-application-on-login)

Comment: this is good but i want it to start after every login not just the first one? will this still work?

Comment: When you say every login, are you talking about each time a user is fully logging into the machine?  If so, yes, I believe this should work though you'd have to test it.  Now, if you're talking about a user locking their current session, then unlocking the session by providing user credentials, no, this would not work for that, though I'd question why you need to relaunch an already running application at that point.

Comment: no because it's already started.. can you explain what type of program this is..? perhaps someone could give you a better solution

Comment: And I agree with DJ.  The more information the better we can help you :)

Comment: Zarathos link would do the trick but then again I am thinking.. if a user logs in after locking / unlocking the machine..then that would have to be checked.. if it's a Malicious type program that the OP is trying to create meaning capturing Key Strokes and or Spying..then I bid the OP Good luck.. please be more specific on what you need Terri otherwise I will vote to Close this posting

Comment: Could whomever downvoted at least be kind enough to explain why?  Much appreciated!

Comment: ok DJ its not a malicius program i'm just trying to make my computer secure like a second login screen one that i can program with bypasses if i ever forget passwords and one that looks cool.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/474092/Run-Csharp-application-on-Windows-startup-Windows) is what you are looking for man! Here is the relevant snippet:

```
WshShell shell = new WshShell();
string shortcutAddress = startupFolder + @"\MyStartupShortcut.lnk";
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
shortcut.Description = "A startup shortcut. If you delete this shortcut from your computer, LaunchOnStartup.exe will not launch on Windows Startup"; // set the description of the shortcut
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath; /* working directory */
shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath; /* path of the executable */
shortcut.Save(); // save the shortcut
```

Comment: this is good but it has an error creating the shortcut :/ this line of code "IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);"

Comment: Link only answers are bad answers. What happens if the page linked to goes missing?

Comment: ok so this code worked it just needed to be compiled and the error wen't away

Comment: yeah it was good but now its showing the error again :/ sorry here's the error: "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?"

Comment: Man... you can't post errors like this. I can't see your code, I can't see what's going wrong, I don't know which missing reference is being highlighted...

Comment: Anyway... on that page there is also a full working project to download... start by using that one.